# UIPageViewController only for changing Text?

Tags: xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I would like to write an eBook with interaction Methods, so I will need to set up an UIPageViewController with an Array of ViewControllers, but the only tutorials or examples that i have found were changing text of a label things.

Now I would like to know, is it possible to add an Array of Viewcontrollers or Views to an UIPageViewController and to swipe between the Controllers?!?

Because I need a button on every page, which calls a IBAction...

Does anybody have a tutorial or sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. In the method

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
  viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

return the view controller instance you want. You can find a tutorial on UIPageViewController, where you can swipe between view controllers [here](http://www.ioslearner.com/implementing-uipageviewcontroller-programatically-without-storyboarding/).